# Transfer digital data over ham radio frequencies using QPSK modulation SSB-QPSK transmitter

Tags: software-defined-radio, digital-modes, transceiver, ssb, psk31

If I use QPSK modulator/demodulator is it possible to transfer digital data over ham radio frequencies.
SSB-QPSK transmitter

Comment: Do you want to do qpsk or ssb-qpsk? Two different schemes. See the Nokia patent on ssb-qpsk.

Comment: And psl31's qpsk mode is a bit different, too.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible.

The physics and the math don't care what the legal assignment of some RF band is - so you can do any working modulation method on a ham band. Nothing is special about ham bands.